# Reading many pdf files in python

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, text

Having bunch of PDF files with text in one directory. My idea to be able to read them all at once and save in a dictionary. Now I'm able to do it only one by one by using `textract` library like this:

```
import textract

text = textract.process('/Users/user/Documents/Data/CLAR.pdf', 
                        method='tesseract', 
                        language='eng')
```

How is it possible to read them at once? Do I need to use `for` loops for searching in directory or smth other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution might be using `os library` with `for loop`

```
import os
import textract

files_path = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir()]

# Excluding not .pdf files
files_path = [pdf for pdf in files_path if '.pdf' in pdf]

pdfs = []
for file in files_path:
    text = textract.process(file,
                            method='tesseract',
                            language='eng')

    pdfs += [text]
```

1. Get all files in the current directory
2. Exclude not `.pdf` files
3. Save the text into a list (could be different data structure)